# How to do a Lee’s Tetrahedral Conformal Projection of Antarctic/South pole on QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, antarctica

I want to do map of Antarctic using the Lee's Tetrahedral conformal map projection as the image below using QGIS version 3.4. Is it possible to make a custom CRS to do it? If yes, what's the parameters?[image]

Comment: QGIS uses the PROJ library for map projection support and it's not in there. You could add a feature request [here](https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/issues). You would need a github account,

Comment: I will! But is it possible to do with ArcGIS?

Comment: Not possible either. But you can have a look at https://github.com/d3/d3-geo-polygon to see if it's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The specific projection you are looking for is not yet supported by Proj, hence it is not supported by QGIS.

However, you can play around with some less-common projections, which might help you/other people see things differently ;)

Start changing the CRS, and defining a `Custom CRS`

[image]

A couple of funny examples:

### Adam's Word in a Square

`+proj=adams_ws1`

[image]

### Adams Hemisphere in a Square

beware this is an *hemi*spehere in a square :), so you need to set the `+lon_0` parameter if a different view is needed:

`+proj=adams_hemi`

[image]

and its "dark side":
`+proj=adams_hemi +lon_0=180`

[image]

### HEALPix

**Edit:**
I found out also this one, which is peculiar:

`proj +proj=healpix +lon_0=0 +a=1`

[image]

I find this interesting since it was originally conceived to map [CBR (Cosmic Background Radiation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_background_radiation).